# node.js exec and bash script

Tags: node.js, bash

I am using nodejs. The idea is to launch a bash script using exec. I can do it. 
In my bash script I am doing a video conversion using mencoder. For exemple:

```
mencoder Videoinput.ogv -o videouput.avi   -oac lavc -ovc lavc -lavcopts vbitrate=3000 vcodec=mpeg4
```

The problem I have: If I try to convert a huge video, the conversion is ok until a specific time. In my case 1minute 47 seconds..... So it seems like node has a time maximum to execute a bash script using exec and then it cuts it.
Am I right? Does anyone know how to add more time to the exec command? If that is possible, I would be able to finish the video conversion ... thanks for your answer.

Comment: According to [the fine manual](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback), `timeout` is 0, meaning that Node will allow the process all the time it needs. But, if for example your script isn't reading the output generated by mencoder, it might fill up the output buffer and Node will kill your process once the buffer is full (see `maxBuffer`). Please post how you're calling your script from Node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes sense that js does not allow subprocesses to run more than a specific time.  Otherwise the browser can easily become unresponsive.

I'd propose to run a command which terminates quickly but has started the `mencoder` in a split-off parallel process.  It could be enough to append a `&` to the `mencode` command, putting it into the background by this.  Maybe you would like to send all its output in a specific file (or at least to `/dev/null` to suppress it completely).  Use `> outputfilename` for this.  Probably redirecting the error message also makes sense, so also use `2> errormessagesfilename` or just use `2>&1` after redirecting the standard output to send both streams into the same file.

Maybe you have to create a subshell to fool js into believing the subprocess is finished early.  This can eb done by putting the command into parentheses (`(mencoder …)`).

So you might end up with sth like this:

```
(mencoder Videoinput.ogv \
    -o videouput.avi \
    -oac lavc \
    -ovc lavc \
    -lavcopts vbitrate=3000 vcodec=mpeg4 \
    >/tmp/mencoder.output 2>&1 &) > /dev/null
```

Comment: Node will run external programs asynchronously, so it won't become unresponsive if the program takes some time.

Comment: thanks for your answer... I have been able to run my bash script changing the max buffer to {maxBuffer: 500*1024}... Now it works. It was memory problem...

Comment: @anraT I think that will only temporarily solve your problem, once the output generated by mencoder reaches 500K one day, the problem will reappear. I think the best solution would be to just read the output generated by mencoder (and just don't do anything with it). Or use the `-really-quiet` command line option to limit the output that's generated.

Comment: I have tested -really-quiet converting a video of 1.2 Go mpeg to avi. I have used  the default values of maxbuffer... thanks, it works...

Comment: Redirecting all output to /dev/null as described in my answer will also work.

Comment: Yes it also works... but I have only done a redirection to a file &> /tmp/myfile.log thanks